# Connection Time Out When Delete with API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get connection time out when to try to delete data with API delete in Laravel.

Error:
<-- default "Connection Timed Out" response (504) -->

Any solution to my problem? Because when I run it in my localhost it works properly and I've disabled 'throttle:60,1' in my Kernel.php

this is my code :

```
public function deletefavorit(Request $request, UserFavorit $uFavorit)
{
    $uFavorit = UserFavorit::where('id_user', '=', $request->id_user)
               ->where('id_user_favorit', '=', $request->input('id_user_favorit'))
               ->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Delete Favorit Successfully'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Show your delete code

Comment: Hello,  to help users give you good answers it will really help you to be as detailed as possible.  Based on what you've given, a response to this question would just be an educated guess at best.